# How to extend an array in Java without changing its name

Tags: java, arrays, extend

I wonder if it's possible to extend an array in Java but without changing its name, since I have multiple methods linked to this array. I was thinking of creating a new array with the same name but twice as big, and then copy all elements from the first array to the second. Is this possible?
Basically I want to make an array with accounts at a bank, and if the customer creates so many accounds that the array doesn't have enough elements, it should extend itself.
Thank you for any replies!

Comment: not a Java dev, but if you need an array with a dynamic size isn't a typed Vector a good option ?

Comment: So at the moment my array looks like this: SimpleAccount [] AccountArray = new SimpleAccount[10]; then how do I change it to an ArrayList?

Answer (score 14):

Even if using an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is probably a good advice in many circumstances, there are perfectly legitimate occasions for using *plain old arrays*.

In that case, if you need to resize your array, you might want to investigate one of the [`java.utils.Arrays.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28boolean[],%20int%29) methods. Please note however those won't really *resize* your array. They will merely create a new array and copy common items.

If the new array has a size greater than the old one, the new items will be initialized to some default value (i.e.: `false` for `boolean[]`, `null` for `T[]` -- see the documentation for details). You have to use those function like that:

```
myArray = copyOf(myArray, myNewSize);
```

Remember however that this method will always return a *new* array. Even if the requested size is the same as the original one. If this in *not* desirable, you will have to write something like that:

```
myArray = (myNewSize > myArray.length) ? copyOf(myArray, myNewSize) : myArray;
```

Answer (score 9):

You cannot change the array you have, but can create a new array with the desired type and size, copy data from the original array to the newly created, and then assign it to the original array variable.

**But you shouldn't do this.**

Instead of an array use any implementation of `java.util.List`. `ArrayList` is a good choice for this case, I think.

Comment: Sometimes there is a perfectly legitimate reason why you don't want to use an ArrayList. For example if the source is an array which was created by some other component you cannot change.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a method that i wrote for my Java Programming Class

```
private static double[] extendArraySize(double [] array){
    double [] temp = array.clone();
    array = new double[array.length + 1];
    System.arraycopy(temp, 0, array, 0, temp.length);
    return array;
}
```

It's pretty self explanitory on how it works, although on the way it's used it must have
the array assigned to the method with the arrays name passing as the argument, and the data type of the method must always be the type of array passed in.

example:

```
double [] z = {1,2,3};  //size of z = 3; [0,1,2]   VALUES: [1,2,3]
z = extendArraySize(z); //size of z = 4; [0,1,2,3] VALUES: [1,2,3,0];
```

Sorry if it's explained terribly and i'm sure there's a better way of doing it VIA vectors or ArrayLists. But if you're going to want to extend a primitive array, this is one way of doing it.

Hope I helped =D

Comment: This solution is pretty light on memory, since it allocates only the array what it needs.
On the other hand: you don't need to clone the array into the temp if you return the extended array anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Use an [ArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), it does all of that for you. Simply call `add()` or `addAll()` to append stuff.

Comment: Great! So at the moment my array looks like this: SimpleAccount [] AccountArray = new SimpleAccount[10]; then how do I change it to an ArrayList?

Comment: @Kajsa: `ArrayList<SimpleAccount> accounts = new ArrayList<SimpleAccount>();`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void extendarrayafterinitialization(int [] x){
        Scanner input =new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many values do you need to insert to the Array : ");
        int how=input.nextInt();
        int length=x.length+how;
        int [] all=new int[length];
        int value=0;
        System.out.println(length);
        for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++){
            all[i]=x[i];
            }
            for(int j=x.length;j<length;j++){
                System.out.print("Enter new value : ");
                int index=input.nextInt();
                all[j]=index;
                }
        for(int print : all){
            System.out.println(print);
            }
        }
```