# add object directly in a array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have written a object for a school assignment. now i'm trying to add it to an array so i can add multiple boxes.

my main

```
String name;
        double userInputLength;
        double userInputWidth;
        double userInputHeight;

        // initialise a scanner to be able to read the user input
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        // ask the user for input
        System.out.print ("Enter the name of your box: ");
        // read this input
        name = (reader.nextLine());

        // ask the user for input
        System.out.print ("Enter the length of your box: ");
        // read this input
        userInputLength = (reader.nextDouble());

        // ask the user for input
        System.out.print ("Enter the width of your box: ");
        // read this input
        userInputWidth = (reader.nextDouble());

        // ask the user for input
        System.out.print ("Enter the height of your box: ");
        // read this input
        userInputHeight = (reader.nextDouble());

        Block blockOne = new Block(name, userInputLength, userInputWidth, userInputHeight);
        System.out.println( blockOne.showBoxAsString());
```

My object

```
package model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Block {

    // name variable of the figure
    private String name;

    // dimension variable of the figure
    private double blockWidth;
    private double blockHeight;
    private double blockLength;

    public Block() {

    }

    // form a block
    public Block(String N, double L, double W, double H){
        this.name = N;
        this.blockLength = L;
        this.blockWidth = W;
        this.blockHeight = H;
    }

    // set the name
    public void setBlockName(String N){ this.name = N; }
    // set the name
    public String getBlockName(){ return this.name; }

    //set length method
    public void setLength(double L)
    {
        this.blockLength = L;
    }
    //get length method
    public double getLenght(){
        return this.blockLength;
    }


    //set width method
    public void setWidth(double W)
    {
        this.blockLength = W;
    }
    //get width method
    public double getWidth(){
        return this.blockWidth;
    }


    //set height method
    public void setHeight(double H)
    {
        this.blockLength = H;
    }
    //get height method
    public double getHeight(){
        return this.blockHeight;
    }


    // method to calculate the surface of the shape (in this situation its a box)
    public double calcSurfaceBox(){
        // the formula to calculate the surface of the box is length times the width
        double surface = 2 * (this.blockHeight * this.blockWidth) +
                         2 * (this.blockLength * this.blockHeight) +
                         2 * (this.blockWidth * this.blockLength) ;

        // return the calculated value of surface
        return surface;
    }

    // method to calculate the volume of the shape (in this situation it's a box)
    public double calcVolumeBox(){
        // the formula to calculate the volume is length times width times height
        double volume = this.blockLength * this.blockWidth * this.blockHeight;

        // return the calculated value of volume
        return volume;
    }

    // a method to print a string to show the user the size of the shape (in this case a box.)
    public String showBoxAsString(){
        return String.format( "The box has a name: " + getBlockName() + "\n" +
                              "The box has a Length of: " + getLenght() + "\n" +
                              "The box has a Width of: " + getWidth() + "\n" +
                              "The height of the box is: " + getHeight());
    }

}
```

i searched for multiple solutions but i can't figure it out. Is there anyone that could give me some tools or an idea?

my goal is to make my main code as clean as possible. so if anyone got an idea how i can simplify my main code that would be awesome.

Comment: create an array and loop after new scanner(); do let me know if you need more explicit code

Comment: Either you do `someArray[index] = someValue` or this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463028/how-to-extend-an-array-in-java-without-changing-its-name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialise an array of Block Objects
 `Block blocks[] = new Block[length];`
To access each object use `blocks[index]`
Note: The array elements here store the reference variables to the object
Edit: index here means a block object perhaps blockOne